# Can't do constant encoding using MediaCodec on Android Tablet

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration, encoder, android-mediacodec

I am trying to use MediaCodec for hardware encoder on Samsung Tablet GT-P5100. But I only can get a few frames. The preview can get the constant video information and show it but there is something wrong with the encoder function after several frames.

Here is the log

```
11-21 11:06:47.746: V/TAG(2869): FRAME NUM145
11-21 11:06:47.746: V/myCamera(2869): encodec2 called
11-21 11:06:47.746: E/TAG(2869): exception in encode2 msg=null
11-21 11:06:47.753: D/dalvikvm(2869): GC_CONCURRENT freed 17K, 51% free 3817K/7696K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 21ms
11-21 11:06:47.800: D/dalvikvm(2869): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1350K, 68% free 2467K/7696K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
11-21 11:06:47.800: I/dalvikvm-heap(2869): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.453MB for 1382416-byte allocation
11-21 11:06:47.816: V/TAG(2869): FRAME NUM146
11-21 11:06:47.816: V/myCamera(2869): encodec2 called
11-21 11:06:47.816: E/TAG(2869): exception in encode2 msg=null
11-21 11:06:47.824: D/dalvikvm(2869): GC_CONCURRENT freed 17K, 51% free 3817K/7696K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 22ms
11-21 11:06:47.871: D/dalvikvm(2869): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1350K, 68% free 2467K/7696K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
11-21 11:06:47.878: I/dalvikvm-heap(2869): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.453MB for 1382416-byte allocation
```

Part of my code as follow:

```
        codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);     
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,                     MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar );
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
        codec.configure(mediaFormat, null /* surface */, null /* crypto */, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE /* flags */); 

    codec.start();
```

And the encoder function:

```
public void encodec2(File file,byte[] src)
    {

        Log.v("myCamera", "encodec2 called");


        int len = 0;
        try{
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ByteBuffer[]  inputBuffer ;
                ByteBuffer[]  outputBuffer;
                inputBuffer = HWEncoder.codec.getInputBuffers();
                outputBuffer = HWEncoder.codec.getOutputBuffers();

                int indexInput;
                int indexOutput = 0;
                BufferInfo  info = new BufferInfo();
                byte[] inData = src;// = buffer.poll();

                indexInput = HWEncoder.codec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);

                Log.v("myCamera", "encodec2 Input:    "+String.valueOf(indexInput));

                if(indexInput >= 0){
                    int xxx = inData.length;
                         inputBuffer[indexInput].clear();
                           inputBuffer[indexInput].put(inData);
                           HWEncoder.codec.queueInputBuffer(indexInput, 0, inData.length, 0, MediaCodec. BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME);
//                           codec.queueInputBuffer(indexInput, 0, inData.length, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG);
                           //inData = null;
                }

                indexOutput = HWEncoder.codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 0);
                if(indexOutput >= 0){
                        indexOut++;
                }else{
//                                    Log.e(TAG,"empty out frame numOut = "+indexOut);
                }


                Log.v("myCamera", "encodec2 Output:     "+String.valueOf(indexOutput));


                while(indexOutput >= 0){
                    //get a nalu 
                    int size_buf = info.size;
                    byte [] h264  =  new  byte[size_buf];
                    outputBuffer[indexOutput].get(h264);

                    int kkk = h264.length;

                    Log.v("myCamera", "encodec2 Output size:     "+String.valueOf(kkk));

                     FileOutputStream fos = null;

                        try {

                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
                        fos.write(h264);
                        fos.flush();                    
                        fos.close();
                        }catch (Exception ex) {
                            Log.v("System.out", ex.toString());
                        }

                        len += info.size;

                        HWEncoder.codec.releaseOutputBuffer(indexOutput, false);
                     indexOutput = HWEncoder.codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info,100);




                }


        }catch(Exception e){    
                Log.e("TAG","exception in encode2 msg="+e.getMessage()+"");
        }



}
```

Does anyone has any idea? Thank you!

Comment: You need to be more specific about the failure mode -- "there is something wrong" is too vague.  Depending on what you're doing, http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#CameraToMpegTest may be of interest.

Comment: The problem is I just could save the first several frames, but failed to save the others. However, when I run this demo on Nexus, it could save frames constantly. Thank you!

Comment: So it starts out okay, then starts throwing an exception after 145 frames?  If you put `e` as the 3rd argument to `Log.e`, you'll see the full exception (type, message, backtrace) instead of just "msg=null", which might provide useful information.